# Delete last printed character from screen

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a piece of code that sorts a file and then prints formatted output on screen

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(('sort', '-nr',tempfile), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen (('awk', '{print \""$2"\\":\" $1\"},\"} ' ),stdin=p1.stdout)
```

When I run it, gives me like this:

```
/tmp/whois.conf":382},
/tmp/yum.conf":970},
/tmp/hi/bhutpret":0},
```

But I need only as:

```
/tmp/whois.conf":382},
/tmp/yum.conf":970},
/tmp/hi/bhutpret":0}
```

It print comma "," for the last line too . How to delete this already printed comma from the console via program ?

Comment: There's no standard way of doing that, also if you are outputting to a pipe or file there is no way of doing that at all. Only output what you intent to output and nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't print the comma for last line.

```
import subprocess
tempfile='input.txt'
p1 = subprocess.Popen(('sort', '-nr',tempfile), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen (('awk', r'NR > 1 { printf(",\n") } { printf("%s\":%s}", $2, $1) } END{print ""}'),stdin=p1.stdout)
```

Output:

```
is":Pizza},
the":Keep},
really":I},
someone":Did}
```

My file 'input.txt'

```
I really love christmas
Keep the change ya filthy animal
Pizza is my fav food
Did someone say peanut butter?
```